# python When press TAB then mouse cursor can move to next textctrl -wxpython

Tags: python, tabs, wxpython, cursor, textctrl

I use wxpython to do that when press TAB then can move cursor from textctrl_1 to textctrl_2 , how to do this?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kNoym.jpg)

Comment: Could you show what you've tried so far?

Comment: You MUST show us a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) demonstrating the problem you have encountered. Using TAB to move to the next control is already built into wxPython [(see this code)](https://pastebin.com/sDNpAk4Q)